# Django: На сервере при DEBUG = False пишет что DEBUG все равно True

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

в файле settings.py у меня

```
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

на сервере при выдаче 404 выдает

> You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django
>   settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a
>   standard 404 page.

Сервер работает с Nginx, Ajenti, Django и Gunicorn. Подскажите что можно сделать, чтобы при попдании на 404 - мне выдавало стандартную ошибку Nginx

Comment: вы же передоверили обработку запросов вашей *cgi-программе. при чём тут тогда nginx и его «стандартная ошибка»?

Answer (score 2):

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
```

Но сработает только для папок статики.

Стандартная 404 ошибка ngnix находится в html файле, поставьте его в качестве 404 шаблона django если нужна такая страница, можно по симлинку.

DEBUG=FALSE - будет вывод шаблона из папки, если он не срабатывает, нужно проверить код на сайте, может быть не перезаписалось и так же проверить что ничего ниже не подключено, где TRUE, может быть перезапись переменной.

Answer (score 0):

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [<пропиши сюда имя хоста своего или локалки>]